# Catching std::exception and ERROR_STATUS

Tags: c++, exception, std

In my code I use my defined BasicException

```
enum class MyError {
    ERROR_1,
    ERROR_2
};

class BasicException
{
public:
    BasicException(MyError err): _err(err) {}
    get_error() const {return _err;}
private:
    MyError _err;
}
```

The problem is that I was told that BasicException should inherit from std::exception. But then, When I will catch (const std::exception& e) I won't be able to retrieve the MyError of the specific error. So what good is in it?

I'm not sure what will be the optimal solution - But maybe if std::exception had a constructor that receives error value it would solve it.

Comment: you can still catch a child class of `std::exception`

Comment: But then I missed the whole point. I got nothing of making this change. I still need to catch my BasicException and std::exception separately.

Comment: The point of inheriting from `std::exception` is that if the caller is not expecting your specific exception they can still always try to catch `std::exception` and still catch the exception and get something useful out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specifically catch `BasicException`, catch it first like this :

```
try
{

}
catch( BasicException& be )
{
    // your exception here
}
catch( std::exception& e )
{
    // other exceptions here
}
```

And if you want to catch all exception including yours ( if `BasicException` inherit of `std::exception` ), then  :

```
try
{

}
catch( std::exception& e )
{
    // all exceptions here
}
```